# From when can I get a dataset of tagged images?

Tags: data-request

I am looking for an open dataset of tagged images. The number of distinct tags must be in the range of around ~1000 with ~50 images per tag. An image can have multiple distinct tags.

Answer (score 0):

flickr has had this for almost a decade now.

Comment: are you joking? flickr is the poster child of tagged images.